# Why $n!^{(1/n)}$ behaves like an arithmetic progression?

Tags: roots, factorial

The sequence $(n!)^{(1/n)}$ is an increasing sequence. Here are some terms,

$$ 1,1.4142, 1.8171,2.2133, 2.6051,2.9937,....$$

Could someone explain why this sequence is so close to an arithmetic progression?

Comment: A more elementary approach to show that $\sqrt[n]{n!}$ behaves like $n/e$ is to use the fact that if you have a sequence of positive terms $\{u_n\}$ and the limit
$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_{n+1}/u_{n}$ exists, then the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[n]{u_n}$ exists and coincides with the first limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stirling's formula says that asymptotically, 
$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n.$$
Taking $n$th roots, we get that your expression is asymptotic to $n/e,$ which is an arithmetic progression.

Answer (score 3):

The first step in an explanation is [Stirling's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation):

$$n!\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n$$

so that

$$n!^{1/n}\approx (\sqrt{2\pi n})^{1/n}\frac ne.$$

The $(\sqrt{2\pi n})^{1/n}$ part rapidly approaches 1, so can be disregarded, and the common difference of your terms is simply $\frac1e\approx 0.367$.

[This blog post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/) of Terry Tao explains where Stirling's formula comes from.

Answer (score 1):

Stirling's approximation tells you that $n! \approx e^{n\log n - n}$. So $(n!)^{1/n}\approx e^{\log n - 1} = n\cdot e^{-1}$. Here are some terms of that sequence: $1.10364, 1.47152, 1.8394, 2.20728, 2.57516, 2.94304, 3.31091$.